# Getting "Compilation unit analysis terminated" errors in PL/SQL code

Tags: plsql, types, subtype

This is a subtype of "base_t". When I add the "set_name" or "set_genus" I get some errors.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  TYPE dwarf_t UNDER base_t
  ( name  VARCHAR2(30)
  , genus VARCHAR2(30)
  , CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION dwarf_t
  ( name      VARCHAR2
  , genus     VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  , OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION get_name RETURN VARCHAR2 
 -- , OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION set_name (name VARCHAR2)
   , MEMBER FUNCTION get_genus RETURN VARCHAR2
   , MEMBER FUNCTION set_genus (genus VARCHAR2)
  , OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION to_string RETURN VARCHAR2)
  INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/
```

For reference, I have created get_name in the main type, but not set_name, or get/set_genus.

My errors are as follows:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following: 
return
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00565: DWARF_T must be completed as a potential REF target (object type)
```

Comment: When presenting code/errors here, please add it in a code block, and do not add `<br>` line breaks - they will just have to be removed, and that it is a cumbersome operation.

Answer (score 1):

The (not-so-helpful) error message is because you have a function without a return type.  Since this is a SET, I assume you want a procedure instead of a function.

Change this line:

```
MEMBER FUNCTION set_genus (genus VARCHAR2)
```

To this:

```
MEMBER PROCEDURE set_genus (genus VARCHAR2)
```